# encounter "Error configuring application listener of class org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrListener"

Tags: tomcat6, dwr

i found the error of "Error configuring application listener of class org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrListener" when deploying application using dwr in tomcat6.
Here is my web.xml

```
<display-name>DWR (Direct Web Remoting)</display-name>
  <description>A Simple Demo DWR</description>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <description>Direct Web Remoter Servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>

<!-- This should NEVER be present in live -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>debug</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- Remove this unless you want to use active reverse ajax -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- By default DWR creates application scope objects when they are first
used. This creates them when the app-server is started -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>initApplicationScopeCreatorsAtStartup</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- WARNING: allowing JSON-RPC connections bypasses much of the security
protection that DWR gives you. Take this out if security is important -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>jsonRpcEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- WARNING: allowing JSONP connections bypasses much of the security
protection that DWR gives you. Take this out if security is important -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>jsonpEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- data: URLs are good for small images, but are slower, and could OOM for
larger images. Leave this out (or keep 'false') for anything but small images -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>preferDataUrlSchema</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- This enables full streaming mode. It's probably better to leave this
out if you are running across the Internet -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>maxWaitAfterWrite</param-name>
  <param-value>-1</param-value>
</init-param>


    <init-param>
  <param-name>org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerLoadMonitor</param-name>
  <param-value>org.directwebremoting.impl.PollingServerLoadMonitor</param-value>
 </init-param>



<!--
For more information on these parameters, see:
- http://getahead.org/dwr/server/servlet
- http://getahead.org/dwr/reverse-ajax/configuration
-->
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you are getting a ClassNotFound error as well ?

Have you placed `dwr.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp?

Comment: i re-install the tomcat and the error message somehow change to SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dwr-invokerjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
then i include the library in to lib/ and the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for much,it solves my problem.Can imagine that the IDE is so stupid that it does not know to copy the jar automatically.

Comment: @DiveInto: if the IDE is so stupid. Do not use it. :-P